# Street Name in CLLocationManagerDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

How to implement this to show **ALWAYS** street name? Now i have only sometimes street name, but always City Name. How it works?

I'm using `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in my class, and i want to have:

```
Warsaw, Mickiewicza
```

But sometimes in the same location i'm getting only:

```
Warsaw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geocoding will try to return its 'best guess' as to the user's location.  This depends on factors such as the available accuracy, nearby landmarks and so on.  If it is not returning a street name, perhaps the GPS accuracy is insufficient to estimate the nearest street, and there are no other landmarks nearby in the database.  The GPS subsystem needs a few minutes to "warm up" and get an accurate lock.

Try waiting a short time and retrying the geocoding lookup.  Note though that reverse geocoding is quite expensive, and the servers will often throttle your client if you make requests too frequently.

- [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/UsingGeocoders/UsingGeocoders.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH4-SW5)

Comment: Thanks, I thought that problem is connection to your solution, but your explanation is VERY helpful to me. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! There's some useful info in the CoreLocation guide (link added above).